# Cannot run Mocha with CoffeeScript

Tags: coffeescript, mocha.js

Makefile - Content:

```
REPORTER = dot

all: build

build:
    @./node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee \
        -c \
        -o lib src

clean:
    rm -rf lib
    mkdir lib

watch:
    @./node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee \
        -o lib \
        -cw src

test:
    @./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha \
        --reporter $(REPORTER) \
        test/*.coffee

.PHONY: build clean watch test
```

The project root directory has a test folder with two files: mocha.opts and example.coffee

example.coffee - Content

```
describe "feature", ->
   it "should add two numbers", ->
       (2+2).should.equal 4
```

On running `make test`, getting the following error:

```
cribe 'feature',
      ^^^^^^^^^

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected string
    at Module._compile (module.js:429:25)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (module.js:370:17)
    at /home/my_username/testcode/coffeepress/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:261:27
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at load (/home/my_username/testcode/coffeepress/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:258:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/my_username/testcode/coffeepress/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:249:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Array.0 (module.js:479:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
```

Running Mocha with js files succeeds, but cannot get it to run with CoffeeScript. I really want to - for code brevity.

Please guide.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

As of Mocha 1.0:

> coffee-script is no longer supported out of the box. CS and similar transpilers may be used by mapping the file extensions (for use with --watch) and the module name. For example `--compilers coffee:coffee-script` with CoffeeScript 1.6- or `--compilers coffee:coffee-script/register` with CoffeeScript 1.7+.

(Quoting http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/#compilers-option) So, you need to add the line

```
--compilers coffee:coffee-script/register
```

or, for CS <= 1.6.x,

```
--compilers coffee:coffee-script
```

to your `mocha.opts` file.

Comment: That link is broken and `--compilers` has been deprecated https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/compilers-deprecation

Answer (score 28):

From CoffeeScript 1.7 onwards, the option should be:

```
--compilers coffee:coffee-script/register
```

An [issue](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/issues/1120) was filed on Mocha's github site.

Comment: Maybe update this to reflect v2 onwards and thus the lack of a dash.  `coffee:coffeescript/register` worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, a change in Mocha made in April 2018 (softly) deprecated the `--compilers` option. In the command line you now get:

> (node:27864) DeprecationWarning: "--compilers" will be removed in a future version of Mocha; see https://git.io/vdcSr for more info

Like the link says, this can easily be fixed by just not using `--compilers` and using this new (simplified) `mocha.opts` options:

```
--require coffeescript/register

test/*.coffee
```

The last line is needed to make Mocha understand it should now use `*.coffee` files as test files. This seems not to be covered with the `--require` option.

Comment: Depending on whether you have the older `coffee-script` or the new `coffeescript` (no dash) installed from npm, you will need `--require coffee-script/register` or `--require coffeescript/register`.

Answer (score 1):

`mocha --require coffeescript/register`

Source: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/compilers-deprecation

Answer (score 1):

with the latest update of mocha the the require statement must written in package.json file as

```
  "mocha":{
    "require":"coffeescript",
    "reporter":"spec"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed two changes to my mocha args to get this to work:

```
--require coffee-script/register
--compilers coffee:coffee-script/register
```