# Tell Mocha to use CoffeeScript files by default

Tags: node.js, makefile, mocha.js, zappa

I'm currently trying to set up testing in Mocha for an application I'm writing using Zappa.js. So far I've been following [this tutorial](http://brianstoner.com/blog/testing-in-nodejs-with-mocha/), and converting what I need from JS to Coffeescript.

However I'm a little stuck with trying to run tests. I have a Makefile, which currently looks like this:

```
REPORTER = dot

test:
  @NODE_ENV=test ./node_modules/.bin/mocha \
    --reporter $(REPORTER) \

.PHONY: test
```

And I've set up my package.json file to run tests like so:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "make test"
  }
}
```

The issue I'm finding is that, because I'm trying to write my Mocha tests using Coffeescript as well, Mocha does not pick up any of my tests in the "test/" folder when I run "npm test". I know for a fact that I can tell Mocha to run .coffee files by using the following in Terminal (which works):

```
mocha --compilers coffee:coffee-script
```

What I want to know is how do I go about telling Mocha to use Coffeescript files by default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK I managed to find a way to solve my own question, so I thought I'd share in case anyone else need this.

NOTE: For CoffeeScript 1.7+ --require coffee-script needs to be changed to --require coffee-script/register

The solution is to instead create a Cakefile as opposed to a Makefile, which looks like this:

```
#Cakefile

{exec} = require "child_process"

REPORTER = "min"

task "test", "run tests", ->
  exec "NODE_ENV=test
    ./node_modules/.bin/mocha
    --compilers coffee:coffee-script
    --reporter #{REPORTER}
    --require coffee-script
    --require test/test_helper.coffee
    --colors
    ", (err, output) ->
      throw err if err
      console.log output
```

And then change the package.json to this:

```
#package.json

{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "cake test"
  }
}
```

Finally I had to install Coffeescript into the project using:

```
npm install coffee-script
```

And create a file test/test_helper.coffee, which contains global declarations for the tests.

Comment: If you want contributors to be able to execute your tests, you'll want to do `npm install coffee-script --save-dev`

Comment: For CoffeeScript 1.7+ `--require coffee-script` needs to be changed to `--require coffee-script/register` http://stackoverflow.com/a/9943255/167815

Answer (score 4):

I configure the mocha tests directly using npm

**package.json (scripts only)**

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node app.js",
  "start-watch": "./node_modules/.bin/node-dev app.js",
  "test": "NODE_ENV=test ./node_modules/.bin/mocha --require coffee-script --compilers coffee:coffee-script --recursive ./test",
  "test-watch": "NODE_ENV=test ./node_modules/.bin/mocha --require coffee-script --compilers coffee:coffee-script --recursive ./test --watch"
}
```

and then execute the test coffeescript files by running

```
npm test
```

or

```
npm run-script test-watch
```

Comment: This **does** work when using `--require coffee-script/register`

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working **Makefile** and **package.json**

**Makefile:**

```
REPORTER = dot
COMPILER = coffee:coffee-script

node_modules:
    @npm install

test: node_modules
    @./node_modules/.bin/mocha --reporter $(REPORTER) --compilers $(COMPILER)

clean: node_modules
    @$(RM) -r node_modules

.PHONY: clean test
```

**package.json (devDependencies only):**

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "coffee-script": "~1.6.3",
    "chai": "~1.7.2",
    "mocha": "~1.12.0"
  }
```

**Then do:**

```
% make clean
% make test
```